# Hiding Scrollview items when there isn't enough room to show them

Tags: react-native

I'm currently developing an app where a list of items are being rendered in a ScrollView that's positioned before and after a View just like shown in the image.

[image]

Now as I scroll the first and last items tend to get occluded by the padding/Views. Is there any way to handle this behavior by making any partially occluded item not make it to the view?

Comment: wait what do you want? a bit unsure? so currently the above happens right?

Comment: I would rather if the ScrollView items that are only partially shown (e.g., 'zx' and 'vd') not make it to the screen in the first place. That is, I'd like the ScrollView to only display items that can be fully displayed.

Comment: I don't think you actually want that behavior, I personally think it would be confusing for a user as there is no suggestion that they can scroll up or down. Typically cut off items indicate that there are more items below or above it and it is scrollable.